# How to make a dynamic HTML table repopulate after form is reopened based on saved value

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form which uses a dropdown, based on the selection in this dropdown a few tables dynamically populate with dynamically created inputs. This all works properly.

The problem is that I have to place this form inside of another HTML/JS/JQuery based 3rd party system and the form will *need to be closed and reopened multiple times on different computers of an intranet*. From what I can tell, this system has a background script (probably using serialization?) that saves the user inputs for any fields that is an input/select/check which allows it to store forms with entered user input.

Given that this system is storing the data for my dropdown selection, I should be able to call my function again to "reset" the table I would think.

I have tried checking if the dropdown is not at the "default" and running the function for setting dropdowns and it did not work.

How can I have my table populate when the form is reloaded?

```
if (document.getElementById('cmblstPartNumber') != "Select Product"){
    setDropdowns(document.getElementById('cmblstPartNumber'),document.getElementById('cmblstLine'));
}
```

This is the function declaration for my functional code to set the dropdowns.

```
function setDropdowns(cmblstPartNumber,cmblstLine) {
//Massive Switch statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected values in local storage and repopulate it when the form element is reloaded.
*Clear the local storage when you are done*

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post that it was on an intranet and would need to be accessed by different clients. Which is why I didn't think I could use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to address my particular problem by creating hidden inputs that mirrored the possible created inputs. Then bound a function to an event that would assign the hidden input to the dynamic input.

```
//Create hidden mirror input to store the input
<input type="hidden" id="hVisual1" name="hVisual1">

//Check if field exists, then assign the hidden field the user input
<script>
if(document.getElementById('Visual1')){
document.getElementById('hVisual1').value = document.getElementById('Visual1').value;
}
</script>
```